# InfluxDb 1.8 Query API raises 403

Tags: influxdb, flux-influxdb

I am using InfluxDb version 1.8. I want to use InfluxDb Query API to query some data and for this I enabled the option in InfluxDb config file i.e. **"flux-enabled = true"** but still getting the below error.

**Flux query service disabled. Verify flux-enabled=true in the [http] section of the InfluxDB config.**

I also tried by adding the environment variable named **"INFLUXDB_HTTP_FLUX_ENABLED"** but didn't get any success.